# Python Enumeration Using List Comprehension and If Statement

Tags: python, if-statement, list-comprehension, enumeration

Is there a way to enumerate in list comprehension where the enumeration only increments when the if statement is True?

For example, the code below enumerates whether the if statement is True or False and I would like to have a continuous index.

`my_list = [0,1,2]
[i for i, w in enumerate(my_list) if w != 1]`

I also tried the following, but you can't use pass inside a list comprehension like below.

```
[i if w != 1 else pass for i, w in enumerate(my_list)]
```

Comment: I see some answers, but I'm not sure I understand what you want as ouptut. Can you give a sample output of what you want?

Comment: This was just a toy example, but I wanted a dictionary comprehension where the value increments without skipping numbers to index the keys. The answers below both provide good ways of implementing what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is. One simple way is to use `itertools.count`:

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count(0)
>>> my_list = [0,1,2]
>>> [next(c) for w in my_list if w != 1]
[0, 1]
```

HOWEVER: This involves state-change inside a list-comprehension, which is just... not good. Note, if you run your comprehension again, this will have unfortunate effects:

```
>>> [next(c) for w in my_list if w != 1]
[2, 3]
>>> [next(c) for w in my_list if w != 1]
[4, 5]
```

Instead, I would do something like:

```
>>> range(sum(w != 1 for w in my_list))
range(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about putting a list comprehension (generator) inside the list comprehension?

```
my_list = [0,1,2]
[i for i, w in enumerate((_ for _ in my_list if _ != 1)) ]
```

Outputs:

```
[0, 1]
```

Comment: hmmm.. maybe not what you asked for if you want to handle the none values